# How to import sample Actionbarsherlock projects in eclipse and use them

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to import some of the sample projects comes with ABS kit, how to import and use them in Eclipse.
I used Github plugin to download the ABS lib.
If I give directory path by normal import wizard, it says no Android project found.

Comment: You need to set up a "New Project" > "From Existing Source", as explained in the [getting started video](http://youtu.be/4GJ6yY1lNNY) by Graham Smith (which is also available in the FAQ section on the ActionBarSherlock website).

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the Import menu wizard.  Create a New Android Project and select the "From existing source" option.  Also, make sure that you are loading this from outside of your Workspace directory (meaning, don't copy the source into a directory at any level with your Workspace).

Follow along with this guy, and you'll be set:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avcp6eD_X2k